# Would the word "tween" be considered a portmanteau or is it just a truncation?

Tags: etymology, slang, portmanteau-words

Is it the word "between", but truncated, or a portmanteau of "in between" and "teen"?

Comment: If it means [*tweenager*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tweenager) then it's a truncation of a portmanteau word.

Comment: _Tween_ is also a word used in computer animation. Here is a definition from About.com: _"Tween" is actually short for "in-between", and refers to the creation of successive frames of animation between key frames._ http://animation.about.com/od/glossaryofterms/g/tween_def.htm

Comment: @AndrewLeach, Isn't "a truncation of a portmanteau word" also considered a portmanteau?

Comment: Holy thread resurrection, Batman! @Pacerier: if one can be more precise about how a particular portmanteau word is formed, why not be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/portmanteau)'s definition of *portmanteau*:

> word or morpheme whose form and meaning are derived from a blending of two or more distinct forms (as *smog* from *smoke* and *fog*)

Here's [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tween)'s definition of *tween*:

> A child between middle childhood and adolesence, usually between 8 and 12 years old. [Blend of teen and between.]

The OED says *tween* is short for *tween-age*, after *teen*. For *tween-age*, they say it's an alteration of *teenage* after *'tween* (a form of *between*).

So, yes, *tween* can be considered a portmanteau of "[in] between" and "teen".